# MVC5 Lockout User not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Based on the guides I've read online, to lockout the user after x many attempts you have to configure the manager like this:

```
manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 1;
```

Then

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(dto.Email, dto.Password, dto.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
```

When I tried this my users never get locked out.  I was monitoring the database and I see the following fields:

```
LockoutEndDateUtc          LockoutEnabled   AccessFailedCount
2016-04-23 21:33:18.777           0                0
2016-04-23 21:32:36.470           1                0
```

The AccessFailedCount never increases  and the Lockout Enabled for both accounts doesn't seem to matter, I tried locking both.

EDIT:

I am wondering if the problem is with the way I am injecting:

**Startup.cs**

```
private IAppBuilder _app;
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
    _app = app;
    app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel);
}

private IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    kernel.Bind<DbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<IDbContext>().To<DbContext>().InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<IUserStore<User>>().To<ApplicationUserStore>();
    kernel.Bind<UserService>().ToSelf();
    kernel.Bind<SignInService>().ToSelf();
    kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationManager>().ToMethod(x => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
    kernel.Bind<IDataProtectionProvider>().ToMethod(x => _app.GetDataProtectionProvider());

    return kernel;
}
```

Comment: check the value of `manager.SupportsUserLockout` and verify it's `true`

Comment: @Shoe yes it is set to true

Comment: Set `user.LockoutEnabled = true;` to enable lockout on user-level. Read more here: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/asp-net-identity-user-lockout/

Comment: @trailmax the article you linked above warns not to lock out user in such a way.  It says that I should lockout the user in the way I am already attemtping.

Comment: You are missing `LockoutEnabled` set to `true` on a user record. That is all you missing.

Comment: @trailmax I have `manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;` that does the same thing.

Comment: No it does not. `manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault` is the default setting for new users - can they be locked out or not. Only applicable on user creation. `User.LockoutEnabled` is a setting on the user entity showing if a user can be locked out at all or not. If `User.LockoutEnabled` is false, this user can't be locked out at all, even if you set `manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault` to true and if you use `shouldLockOut: true` on SignInManager.

Comment: @trailmax I assume you are basing this on the database record I showed in the question.  One of the users is enabled, the other disabled.  My lockout does not works for either of them.  I did more testing and created a new project and the lockout works with this same database for the user that has it enabled.  There is something else in my code that is preventing and I'm still trying to troubleshoot what.

Comment: @Bojan Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell this was so long ago, I don't remember how and if I solved it, sorry. I've since moved on  to .NET Core and haven't had that issue there.

Answer (score 0):

### Failed Attempts Count in ASP.NET MVC

Recently I also found this out and my solution was to manually increment the failed attemps. It automatically resets when maximum is reached and a timed account lock is activated.

```
if (!UserManager.CheckPassword(usr, password)) {
    // incorrect password... increment failed count
    if (UserManager.AccessFailed(usr.Id) != IdentityResult.Success) {
        // increment of failed attempt gave an error
        Log.Err("Error Message");
    }
    // warn the user
    return View(model);
}
```

`IdentityConfig.cs` file has:

```
// configure user lockout defaults
manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
```

And if the account is locked, this code checks for it:

```
if (UserManager.IsLockedOut(usr.Id)) {
    // account locked, too many attempts
    // warn user - number of minutes locked = UserManager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan.Minutes
    return View(model);
}
```